# Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'armv7' in xcode 4.6

Tags: iphone, ios, gcc, zxing

I accidentally updated my iphone to 6.1 and when that happened I came to know that I have to update the xcode version too to Version 4.6 (4H127), which I did. I had a requirement to read qrcode for which I was using Zxing and it was working perfectly well. After all updates, its throwing an error with build failed. The error says
**"Unsupported compiler 'GCC 4.2' selected for architecture 'armv7'"**
I tried searching for the answer changed the compiler from Default to LLVM GCC 4.2 from default that is APPLE LLVM Compiler 4.2 but with no change.

Please guide me to resolve the issue.

[image: Target of my project(Build Settings]

[image: Build Settings(Project)]

Comment: Did you refer this http://blog.hozbox.com/2011/11/08/how-to-use-gcc-4-2-with-xcode-4-2/

Comment: I am using xcode 4.6 which is just released and I have already downloaded in installed it.. Do I have to change anything in it?

Comment: XCode 4.2 also had the same problem which you are facing in XCode 4.6. I'd suggest you to follow the same steps.

Comment: then what I have to do...delete the xcode 4.6 and then download it again and follow the steps?

Comment: Yes you'll have to uninstall,follow the steps and install it again.

Comment: dont! :) GCC is out for good for a reason!

Comment: so I guess...I will have to reinstall the xcode using http://blog.hozbox.com/2011/11/08/how-to-use-gcc-4-2-with-xcode-4-2/
to resolve the issue. There is no other alternatives??????

Comment: where do I to get the xcode4.6.dmg?

Comment: I didnt have to uninstall it @Rushi.....Simply tweaking some settings like same compiler settings for all associated projects, same architecture for all have solved my issues. Thanx for the suggestion though.